# Making an autocomplete field for locations using Facebook Places

Tags: facebook-graph-api, autocomplete

I'm looking to make something similar to the location autocomplete in Facebook's "Create Event" page. It gives location name, address, and number of check-ins. Do you know how is it done? Because the Places table does not have any field for address and nubmer of checkins.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place/

I was going to use Factual, but after some trial and error, found out that facebook is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this query. It ensures that the checkins field is also returned as part of the search request.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&fields=location,name,id,checkins

Comment: thanks Karan. Is there also any way to sort the results based on distance from center?

Comment: How can I retrieve all available fields for a specific object? I couldn't find any documentation for this. I really appreciate it if you tell me the answer in case you know it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a graph place search API.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place

Comment: Yes, but as I said, the response doesn't include checkin times.